# Update value of column A from last month to column B of current month - Sql Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table "`ABC`":

```
ID  CustomId      A              B              Month           Year
1      1         600             0                11            2016
2      1         500             0                12            2016
3      1         100             0                1             2017
4      1         200             0                2             2017
5      1         300             0                3             2017
6      2         300             0                1             2017
7      2         400             0                2             2017
8      2         500             0                3             2017
```

I want to update value of column A from last month to column B of current month.

Comment: choose any one of (MySQL & SQL-Server) which is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tb set b = ta.a
  from abc ta
 inner join abc tb
         on DATEADD(m, cast(ta.year as varchar(10)) + '/'
                       + cast(ta.month as varchar(10)) + '/01'
                     , -1)
            = cast(tb.year as varchar(10)) + '/' + cast(tb.month as varchar(10)) + '/01'
```

Comment: Is this a MySQL or MS SQL Server answer?

Comment: This is for sql Server.  For mySql use the date_add() function, eg DATE_ADD( cast(ta.year as varchar(10)) + '/'
                       + cast(ta.month as varchar(10)) + '/01', interval -1 month)